# Getting the address of an ERC20 Token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am trying to understand how to use the IERC20 token interface. From what I understand, I need to create an instance of an IERC20 token with the address of the token contract. Something like this:

```
IERC20 public token = IERC20(0xABCD...)
```

I am confused about where to find the address of the token.

Comment: Well, it depends... You can search for it on Etherscan or another site, if that's enough for you (that is, if you assume the site is not compromised). If you are just experimenting, that should be enough.

Comment: go to Ethplorer website and pick one address of the top 10 tokens.